# rails has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 simple models

```
class Alpha < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :betas
  has_many :gammas
end

class Beta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha    
  before_create :gen_gamma

  def gen_gamma
    gamma = alpha.gammas.build
    gamma
  end
end

class Gamma < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha
end
```

I want that, whenever a new Beta is created, the should also be a new Gamma. Both are associated to alpha.

Here is my unit test

```
require 'test_helper'

class BetaTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "creating a beta should create a gamma" do
    a = Alpha.new
    b = a.betas.build
    a.save
    assert a.gammas.size > 0, "alpha should have gammas"
  end
end
```

The before_create callback gets called, but the associated gamma is not saved, while the beta is saved.

The strange thing is that

```
a = Alpha.new
b = a.betas.build
g = a.gammas.build
a.save
```

works!

Comment: In the test, use the `!` version of `save` : `a.save!`. Any errors ? And put a breakpoint on `gen_gamma` : is it getting called ?

Comment: even with save! there are no gammas, but the callback is called. I also experimented with the autosave option, or reloading alpha but no success

Answer (score 0):

You are building the gamma but not saving the alpha, which would save the gamma as well. You can use `create` instead of `build` on your gamma to solve that problem. Unlike `build`, `create` saves the record.

```
def gen_gamma
  alpha.gammas.create
end
```

Comment: But, Alpha is being saved (by `a.save`) right? Also, if `a.betas` is being saved, why isn't `a.gammas` being saved? Seems like `gen_gamma` is not getting called, or some other problem. What gives?

Comment: gen_gamma is called, tested with "puts called", it looks like the navigation within the callback alpha.gammas.build does not mark the new gammas to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the `inverse_of` option on `has_many`:

```
class Alpha < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :betas, :inverse_of => :alpha
  has_many :gammas, :inverse_of => :alpha
end

class Beta < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha, :inverse_of => :betas
  before_create :gen_gamma

  def gen_gamma
    alpha.gammas.build
  end
end

class Gamma < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alpha, :inverse_of => :gammas
end
```

Or a simpler way, move the `before_create` into `Alpha` :

```
class Alpha < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :betas
  has_many :gammas
  before_create :gen_gamma

  def gen_gamma
    gammas.build
  end
end
```